# How to configure Quartz Instance to not process jobs

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

We have particular deployment specifics which are requiring us to need to split our Quartz deployment into 2 modules.

- The first module exposes REST endpoints and adds jobs (via the Quartz API) to the database (but should execute no jobs).
- The second module is responsible for executing jobs (but doing no scheduling)

For the first module, is there any way to tell the SchedulerFactory to NOT process any jobs. I tried setting the `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` to zero but it's invalid.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

M

Comment: The Scheduler is processing the jobs not the SchedulerFactory, isnt it? If you do not start it, it should not process any jobs.

Comment: Thanks Volker. Found the autoStartup flag and set it to false.